# Why is my form posting after ajax post? How do I fix this?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

So I have this form:

```
<form method="post" id="login-nav">
        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="PassWord" name="PassWord" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Zaboravili ste password?</a></div>
        </div>
        <button id="submitit" onclick="GetUser();" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
            </label>
        </div>
</form>
```

And when I press on the Sign in button, I send an post and I have my HTML updated correctly for a brief second, and then the page reloads. This is not what I want. I dont want the page to reload, but stay as it is after my ajax call. Here is the javascript/jquery code:

```
function GetUser() {
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#PassWord").val();

$.post('../phpdatabase/getlogin.php',{ email: email , password : password }, function(data){
  $('#LogNav').html(data);
});
}
```

Comment: you need to prevent the default action of the form otherwise you will post and do the js call: `onclick="GetUser(); return false;"`

Comment: change <button id="submitit"> to buttton type="button"

Comment: Better to initiate events via JavaScript instead of initiating them in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of a submit button is to submit the form, so you have to *prevent* it.

```
onclick="GetUser(event);"
```

This will pass the event to the function callback. Insde your function you have to use:

```
function GetUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

---

I would suggest you to change the event from the button to the form `submit` event:

```
$("#login-nav").on("submit", function(e) {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#PassWord").val();

    $.post('../phpdatabase/getlogin.php',{ email: email , password : password }, function(data){
      $('#LogNav').html(data);
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Avoid using *inline* events into your HTML elements e.g. `onclick`, `onfocus` etc...

Answer (score 0):

add type of the button which is `<button type="button"></button>`. Because by default it will assume button type submit if it's under form tag.

```
<form method="post" id="login-nav">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="PassWord" name="PassWord" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Zaboravili ste password?</a></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="submitit" onclick="GetUser(e);" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also you can prevent it by passing event into the function and preventing it in the javascript function. like this

```
function GetUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```